# how to hide angular-ui-grid scrollBar when it's unnecessary?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

> when I use **angular-ui-grid**,I found the HorizontalScrollbar always 
>   appears.  And I try to use  `enableHorizontalScrollbar:2` in gridOptions.    But it doesn't work.and when I show or hide the HorizontalScrollbar like this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/aI6qfDNTMT9RFKkekYoR?p=info).
>   
>   [image]
>   
> The left side's selection will be malposition.
>   
>  any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a size problem, Try to set the width of the column to fit your object size, When you do the horizontal scrollbar will disappear.

Changing the column size to

```
   $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
       { name:'id', width:50},
       { name:'name', width:50 },
       { name:'age', width:50 }
     ];
```

produces a table without horizontal lines

---

In **angular-ui-grid** you have an **autoResize** option,This should solve your problem if the data can actually fit the table.

You can read about it here:
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/213_auto_resizing

Comment: doesn't work for me ,I use the `ui-grid-auto-resize` but the HorizontalScrollbar still there

Comment: here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aI6qfDNTMT9RFKkekYoR?p=preview)

Comment: The most basic solution is to add this to your css  **.ui-grid-           viewport{overflow-x: hidden}**

Comment: I'm doing it in this way now.It actually can deal with this issue.Only a little problem that the VerticalScrollbar missing,but it's ok .Thanks